# How to add the same item to every item in a Ruby array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a date, stored as a string.

```rb
date_added = "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"
```

I need to add that to every item in an array.

```rb
tracks = ["6tIlpznHyaqCPiVfolKxrV", "5sKHRsDybtkw6lxufkyk08", "0ZWBuv544C0STkXfYb9Sd5"]
```

So, the final output should be:

```rb
[["6tIlpznHyaqCPiVfolKxrV", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"], ["5sKHRsDybtkw6lxufkyk08", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"], ["0ZWBuv544C0STkXfYb9Sd5", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"]]
```

How can add that date item to every item in an array? I've looked into `zip` and `push` but wasn't able to get that desired outcome.

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tracks` array contains *strings* whereas the final output contains others *arrays*. Those are different classes and since you can't change the class of an object, "adding" to the existing items doesn't really work. You have to create new elements (arrays) which are composed of one of the old elements (a string) and the `date_added` (another string).

You could use [`product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and let Ruby combine `tracks` with `[date_added]`:

```
tracks.product([date_added])
#=> [["6tIlpznHyaqCPiVfolKxrV", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"],
#    ["5sKHRsDybtkw6lxufkyk08", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"],
#    ["0ZWBuv544C0STkXfYb9Sd5", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"]]
```

or use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to create the sub-arrays:

```
tracks.map { |t| [t, date_added] }
#=> [["6tIlpznHyaqCPiVfolKxrV", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"],
#    ["5sKHRsDybtkw6lxufkyk08", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"],
#    ["0ZWBuv544C0STkXfYb9Sd5", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record:

```
date_added = "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"
racks = ["6tIlpznHyaqCPiVfolKxrV", "5sKHRsDybtkw6lxufkyk08", "0ZWBuv544C0STkXfYb9Sd5"]

racks.zip([date_added] * racks.size) 
# => [["6tIlpznHyaqCPiVfolKxrV", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"],
#     ["5sKHRsDybtkw6lxufkyk08", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"],
#     ["0ZWBuv544C0STkXfYb9Sd5", "2019-12-28T20:32:27Z"]]
```

But, if at all possible, I wouldn't massage the array resulting in expanding its size with redundant information as `zip` or `product` would do. Instead, I'd massage each element as they're being accessed to tack on the date, something like:

```
racks.each do |r|
  foo([r, date_added])
end
```

The end result would be what @Stefan suggested using `map` as long as you didn't store the `map` result in an intermediate value.

Comment: Depending on preference `racks.zip([date_added] * racks.size)` could be replaced with `racks.zip([date_added].cycle)`.

Comment: Cool! I never thought about using `cycle` like that.